# How to add current date as prefix in log file using logging from Python

Tags: python, logging

I would like to name log files based on the current date using Python's `logging` library such as the following example:

```
log/ 

    06-06-2019.log
    07-06-2019.log
    08-06-2019.log
```

However, the code I was able to write...

```
handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(
        'log/log',
        when = 'midnight',
        interval = 1,
        utc = True,
        backupCount = 9
)
```

... produces these log files:

```
log/

   log
   log.2019-06-06
   log.2019-06-07
   log.2019-06-08
```

Is there any event to calculate file name? I have read many SO questions and the official docs but have found nothing useful to this problem.

How do I solve this? If possible, I would like a solution using `logging`library.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `handler.namer = lambda name: name + '.log'`

Comment: @hoefling it works! Thanks. But do you know how to get `backupCount` back? It stopped working so log files are created unstoppably.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this:

```
from datetime import date

log_file = "../Path/To/Logs/Folder/log-" + date.today() + ".log"
logger = open(log_file, "w+")
logger.close() # Do this to make sure python let's go of the file.
```

What this does is create a log file named `log-year-month-date.log` in the path which you chose, as long as the file is not there. However, python holds onto the file, so you need to `close()` it before you start logging to it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I do not want to consider this solution because it will manually open and write my logs. Besides, I would need an entire script to control log purge and creation of log files based on current date. However, thanks for providing a solution.